# Cannot get value of input tag in javascipt function?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value from input tag as numbers and add them and show the result.
Here's what I've tried.

```js
function calculator(z) {
    let x = document.getElementById("first").nodeValue;
    let y = parseInt(document.getElementById("second").innerHTML);
    let res = document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML;
```

```html
<div>
            <label for="">Enter First number</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="first" inputmode="numeric" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Enter Second number</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="second" inputmode="numeric">
        </div>
```

The console shows null value.

Comment: Both `nodeValue` and `innerHTML` would only apply to elements that actually _have_ content in the first place. Use just `value` to read or set the value of text input fields.

Answer (score 0):

you better set type as number in input tag like

```
<input type="number" id="first">
<input type="number" id="second">
```

then there are arrors in your js script, you better use value field of element and parse it just by creating new Number

```
function calculator(z) {
    let x = Number(document.getElementById("first").value);
    let y = Number(document.getElementById("second").value);
    let res = document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML;
```